# Using String[] args as user input and setting values if no input is given

Tags: java, args

If a program relies on command line arguments as user input, like for example asking for an amount of shirts to order, a shirt size, and a color selection. I know these values would be stored in `args[0]`, `args[1]`, and `args[2]`. But how would I manage cases in which one or more of those arguments isn't given by the user if I'm expecting to receive those values in that order. Like if the amount of shirts to order isn't given, is there a way that I can initialize that value to a default value of 1?

Comment: Take a moment to think about this. Say you do `java MyClass foo 5 L red` vs `java MyClass M blue`. How will you determine that the quantity was left out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get very little flexibility with command line arguments: the environment communicates them to you as a `String[]` array, which implies that individual arguments have no names, only indexes.

You need to decide how to handle cases when one or more command-line arguments are missing, but keep in mind that it is not possible to "skip" arguments in the middle: whenever an argument is omitted, it is always the trailing argument. For example, if the user calls your program with parameters `XXL GREEN` these would be placed in `args[0]` and `args[1]`, while `args[2]` would be missing; the parameters would not be placed in `args[1]` and `args[2]`.

One simple choice is to treat situations when fewer than three arguments are specified as errors. If this is not flexible enough, you could parse parameters individually, and try to infer what they "mean". For example, if you see `"S"`, `"M"`, `"L"`, `"XL"`, or `"XXL"` in any position, your program may take it as an indication of size.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common approaches for optional command line arguments

1. Use a flag like `java MyClass -q5`. Parsing these kinds of arguments is challenging to do on your own. I suggest using a library such as [commons-cli](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.3.1).
2. Put the optional arguments at the end. This way if the user supplies only 2 arguments, you know that these are the size and the color.

Answer (score 0):

One trick off the top of my head would be to fix the length of arguments or play around it if there's a pattern.

For your example size is always a number so you can loop around the arguments and reserve the numeric one to your `length`. 
For size you can prompt user to use `X,M,L,XL` so let's say it becomes maximum of two character length then you can again loop around arguments and store it as your `size`. For `color` you can make it string and greater than 2 character like `RED, GREEN` and assign it to your `color` argument. If you want to go further then you can reserve the keywords for your `size` to be one of `S,M,L,XXL,XL` etc and check every argument against it before assigning to `color` argument.
Either way you might have got the point by now, play around the arguments if there's a pattern and assign it.